# python - django extra_context wont show

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form in ListView view using FormMixin that form takes a string lastname
and querys to take a queryset of Account object, I want that Queryset on my template via extra_context.

The form works and I have the queryset that I want, I pass it into self.extra_context and I can see it on console with print BUT it doesn't show in my template. Im feeling stacked, please help me if tou can.

```
class DepartmentFilesListView(LoginRequiredMixin, SelectRelatedMixin,FormMixin, ListView):
    model = FileDetail

    login_url = '/'
    template_name = 'incomingfiles/departmentFileList_All.html'

    context_object_name = 'departmentFiles'

    form_class = ChooseOperatorForm

    success_url = reverse_lazy('incomingfiles:DepartmentFilesListView')

    def __init__(self):
        super(DepartmentFilesListView, self).__init__()
        now = timezone.now()
        self.extra_context = {'title':'Έγγραφα Τμήματος','date':now.date(), 'day':getDay(now.weekday())}

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DepartmentFilesListView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            # for
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)


    def form_valid(self, form):
        lastname = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
        lastname = valuateLastname(lastname)
        self.extra_context['operators'] = Account.objects.filter(
            is_active=True,
            department=self.request.user.department,
            last_name__contains=lastname
        )
        
        print(self.extra_context['operators'])
        return super(DepartmentFilesListView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return super(DepartmentFilesListView, self).form_invalid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter_for_all'] = FileDetailFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        num_in_page = 50
        paginated_filter_for_all = Paginator(context['filter_for_all'].qs, num_in_page)
        filter_for_all_page_number = self.request.GET.get('page')
        filter_for_all_page_obj = paginated_filter_for_all.get_page(filter_for_all_page_number)
        context['filter_context_obj'] = filter_for_all_page_obj

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.department = self.request.user.department
        return FileDetail.objects.filter(Q(Q(apantitiko__operator__department=self.department)
            | Q(departmentassignment__department=self.department)))
```

And this is the sample of my template

```
<div class="col-12 Search-operator-div">
    <div class="row">
        <h2>Αναζήτηση χρεωμένων εγγράφων κατα χειριστή</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="width:100%; border-top: 2px solid #212529;"></div>
    <br>
    <form id="exactΟperator" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            {% for field in form %}
                <div class="col-1 align-self-center">
                    <label id="id_{{ field.name }}_label">{{ field.label }}</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 align-self-center">
                    {{ field }}
                    {{ field.error }}
                    <a role="button" id="cancelOperator" type="button">
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i></a>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="col-1 align-self-center">
                <input id="SearchOperator" type="submit" value="Αναζήτηση" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="row search-operator-div-content">
        {% for operator in operators %}
            <div class="col">
                <a href="{% url 'incomingfiles:OperatorFilesListView' pk=operator.pk %}" class="link-transition btn-link">
                    {{ operator }}</a>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

In my template I can see anything else is in my self.extra_context but anything Im tried to pass in my form_valid function doesn't shown.
It is like my extra_context cant update in this function.

Comment: What's the definition of `self.extra_context`?

Comment: What should be? I Created it in my __init__ function.

Comment: Could you show the `__init__` method? The way to be able to modify context is by using  `context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)` according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview). Is this what you are doing?

Comment: def __init__(self):
        super(DepartmentFilesListView, self).__init__()
        now = timezone.now()
        self.extra_context = {'title':'All Documents', 'date':now.date(), 'day':getDay(now.weekday())}

Comment: The other keys of extra_content like title or date its ok

Comment: @GiorgosV, add your full Class code to your question.

Comment: Could you also provide the code for you template where you are accessing `self.extra_context`? You say **In my template I can see anything else is in my self.extra_context** but how are you passing the context to your template? The best thing is if you could provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well I found a solution but I don't know if that's the correct way to solve that problem.
If you have anything to suggest it will be my pleasure to try it.
To solve my problem I pass the lastname value into the session and query in get_context_data .

```
    def form_valid(self, form):
        lastname = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
        lastname = valuateLastname(lastname)
        if lastname == '':
            lastname = '-'
        elif lastname == '*':
            lastname = ''

        self.request.session['lastname'] = lastname
        # print(self.extra_context['operators'])

        return super(DepartmentFilesListView, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(self.extra_context['operators'])
        return super(DepartmentFilesListView, self).form_invalid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter_for_all'] = FileDetailFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        num_in_page = 50
        paginated_filter_for_all = Paginator(context['filter_for_all'].qs, num_in_page)
        filter_for_all_page_number = self.request.GET.get('page')
        filter_for_all_page_obj = paginated_filter_for_all.get_page(filter_for_all_page_number)
        context['operators'] = Account.objects.filter(is_active=True,
                                                      department=self.request.user.department,
                                                      last_name__contains=self.request.session['lastname'])
        context['filter_context_obj'] = filter_for_all_page_obj

        return context
```

Comment: You can simple use a shortcut: `render()` instead using `session`.

Comment: Why are you doing so complex code ? If you do like this then what is the purpose of using framework ?

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation for `form_valid()` simply redirects to the `success_url`.

So it returns:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

And calling `extra_context_data` is skipped.

**SOLUTION**

Return **`HttpResponse`** instead `super(DepartmentFilesListView, self).form_valid(form)`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    lastname = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
    lastname = valuateLastname(lastname)
    self.extra_context['operators'] = Account.objects.filter(
        is_active=True,
        department=self.request.user.department,
        last_name__contains=lastname
    )
    
    print(self.extra_context['operators'])
    return render(self.request, self.template_name, self.get_context_data())
```

Comment: but I the title and the date is shown as well in my template without do that, and if i try to print(self.extra_context) in get_extra_context , that prints extra_context without the 'operators' or anything else i put in extra_context in form_valid function :(

Comment: i tried that you said and {{ extra_context.operators }} in my template but still wont show ..

Comment: Yeah but when redirects shouldn't call somewhere the extra_content like the get_context_data ?

Comment: @GiorgosV, This is a restriction of HTTP that POST data cannot go with redirects.

Comment: @GiorgosV, i have updated my answer, see another solution.

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is the easiest method:**

```
class SomeListView(ListView):
     .....
     extra_context = self.myquery()
     .....
     def myquery(self):
        return { 'query': QuerySet}
```

**Then in template**

```
{{query}}
```